# Регулярные выражения, как заменить на себя же

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'#.{1,}?#', 
             r',,,,', 
             r'Эта строка #test# написана 19.01.2018,  #x# а могла бы и 01.09.2017'))
```

Пытаюсь заменить все `#text#` на `<>#text#</>`
Для этого я написал регулярное выражение #`.{1,}?#`. Оно работает и в данном коде заменяет все совпадения на `,,,,` . а как можно заменить на `"<>"+то что нашло +"</>"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"То, что нашло" можно задать с помощью обратной ссылки на целое совпадение, `\g<0>`:

```py
re.sub(r'#[^#]+#', r'<>\g<0></>', text)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/KnB8HB/1).

См. [пример кода на Python](https://ideone.com/1zfxbF):

```py
import re
print(
    re.sub(r'#[^#]+#', 
           r'<>\g<0></>', 
           r'Эта строка #test# написана 19.01.2018,  #x# а могла бы и 01.09.2017')
)
# => Эта строка <>#test#</> написана 19.01.2018,  <>#x#</> а могла бы и 01.09.2017
```